# Performant way to change datatable content

Tags: c#, .net, performance, datatable

I have a Datatable with 5000 and more Rows.

For some columns I have to change the value. (123;#Name -> Name)

I tried to do this serveral ways but all of them are very slow.

The obvious variant takes around 1sec per row to change the value. 
And as far as i could all of it is used for assigning the new value.

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    foreach (var column in replaceColumns)
    {
        row[column] = userRegex.Replace(row[column].ToString(), "$1");
    }
}
```

I tried creating a new Table with one column and only the changed values, and merging the two tables. Creating the new table was very fast. Merging the two tables way to slow.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Test2");
dc.DataType = typeof(string);
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(row["Test"]);
}
```

So I tried creating the whole table new, as the single column table was so fast.
Well, it also didn't work. It started with an acceptable speed, but became slower and slower the more rows got inserted.

```
var t = table.Clone();
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    var nr = t.NewRow();
    foreach (DataColumn dc in table.Columns)
    {
        if (replaceColumns.Contains(dc.ColumnName))
        {
            nr[dc.ColumnName] = userRegex.Replace(row[dc.ColumnName].ToString(), "$1");
        }
        else
        {
            nr[dc.ColumnName] = row[dc.ColumnName];
        }
    }
    t.Rows.Add(nr);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how to significantly improve the performance?

Comment: What kind of database are you working against ? (SQLServer, Oracle, etc)   Or is this all in memory ?

Comment: It is all in memory. But i have an SQLServer at my disposal, so if all else fails i could try to perform the update on the sqlserver and reload the data afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this significatly increases performance but you can give it a try. You don't need to check the column-name against your list of column-names in each and every column of every row. Instead you can do it before the loop:

```
DataColumn[] replaceColumns = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(c => new[] { "Column1", "Column2" }.Contains(c.ColumnName))
    .ToArray();

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in replaceColumns)
    { 
        string newStr = userRegex.Replace(row.Field<string>(col), "$1");
        row.SetField(col, newStr);
    }
}
```